# Есть сервер и клиент игры. Как сделать что бы сервер соединял 2х игроков?

Tags: java, java-ee

Клиент

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    private static Socket clientSocket; //сокет для общения
    private static BufferedReader reader; // нам нужен ридер читающий с консоли, иначе как
    // мы узнаем что хочет сказать клиент?
    private static BufferedReader in; // поток чтения из сокета
    private static BufferedWriter out; // поток записи в сокет

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            try {
                // адрес - локальный хост, порт - 4004, такой же как у сервера
                clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4004); // этой строкой мы запрашиваем
                //  у сервера доступ на соединение


                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    // читать соообщения с сервера
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    // писать туда же
                    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Выберите атаку: 1 - в голову, 2 - в корпус, 3 - в пояс, 4 - в ноги"); // если соединение произошло и потоки успешно созданы - мы можем
                    //  работать дальше и предложить клиенту что то ввести
                    // если нет - вылетит исключение
                    String atak = reader.readLine(); // ждём пока человек что-нибудь напечаает
                    System.out.println("1 - защита головы и корпуса, 2 - в корпуса и пояса, 3 - в пояса и ног, 4 - защита ног и головы");
                    String blok = reader.readLine(); // ждём пока человек что-нибудь напечаает
                    out.write(atak  +"\n"); // отправляем  на сервер атаку
                    out.write(blok  +"\n"); // отправляем  на сервер блок
                    out.flush();
                    String serverWord = in.readLine();// 
                    String serverWord2 = in.readLine();// 
                    System.out.println(serverWord);//
                    System.out.println(serverWord2);

                }
            } finally { // в любом случае необходимо закрыть сокет и потоки
                System.out.println("Клиент был закрыт...");
                clientSocket.close();
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Сервер

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;

public class Server {

    private static Socket clientSocket; //сокет для общения
    private static ServerSocket server; // серверсокет
    private static BufferedReader in; // поток чтения из сокета
    private static BufferedWriter out; // поток записи в сокет

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try  {
                server = new ServerSocket(4004); // серверсокет прослушивает порт 4004
                System.out.println("Сервер запущен!"); // хорошо бы серверу
                //   объявить о своем запуске
                clientSocket = server.accept(); // accept() будет ждать пока
                //кто-нибудь не захочет подключиться
                try { // установив связь и воссоздав сокет для общения с клиентом можно перейти
                    // к созданию потоков ввода/вывода.
                    // теперь мы можем принимать сообщения
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    // и отправлять
                    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                    Player Sergio = new Player();
                    int botLife = 20;

                    int yourLife=Player.quantityOfHels;


while (true) {

    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int botAtack = 1 + rnd.nextInt(4 - 1 + 1);
    int botBlock = 1 + rnd.nextInt(4 - 1 + 1);
        int yourAtackThisurn = Player.minFistAtack + rnd.nextInt(Player.maxFistAtack - Player.minFistAtack + 1);





                        String atakString = in.readLine(); // ждём пока клиент пришлет атаку
                        String blokString = in.readLine();// ждём пока клиент пришлет защиту

    int ataka = Integer.parseInt(atakString); // преобразуем в число
    int block = Integer.parseInt(blokString);

                        System.out.println(ataka);
                        System.out.println(block);
    if (ataka==1 &&  botBlock==1 |  botBlock==4) {out.write("Противник заблокировал удар. ");}
    else if (ataka==2 && botBlock==1 |  botBlock==2) {out.write("Противник заблокировал удар. ");}
    else if (ataka==3 && botBlock==3 |  botBlock==2) {out.write("Противник заблокировал удар. ");}
    else if (ataka==4 && botBlock==3 |  botBlock==4) {out.write("Противник заблокировал удар. ");}
    else {botLife=botLife-yourAtackThisurn; out.write("Вы нанесли "+yourAtackThisurn+ " урона. Жизней у противника - "+ botLife+" " ); }
// отправляем результат Вашей атаки  (3ая строка к.о.н.с.)
    if (botAtack == 1 && block == 1 | block == 4) {
        out.write("Вы заблокировали удар. ");
    } else if (botAtack == 2 && block == 1 | block == 2) {
        out.write("Вы заблокировали удар. ");
    } else if (botAtack == 3 && block == 3 | block == 2) {
        out.write("Вы заблокировали удар. ");
    } else if (botAtack == 4 && block == 3 | block == 4) {
        out.write("Вы заблокировали удар. ");
    } else {
        yourLife = yourLife - 3;
        out.write("Вам нанесли 3 урона. У Вас " + yourLife + " жизней ");
// отправляем результат  атаки бота (4ая строка к.о.н.с.)
    }

    out.write("  Атака была : " + ataka + "\n"); // отправляем клиенту атаку
                        out.write("  Блок был : " + block + "\n");

                        out.flush(); // выталкиваем все из буфера

                    }
                } finally { // в любом случае сокет будет закрыт
                    System.out.println("dfjkhgkdf");
                    clientSocket.close();
                    // потоки тоже хорошо бы закрыть
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Сервер закрыт!");
                server.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }}}

 class Player {
     static int strenght = 3; // кол во силы

     static int minFistAtack = strenght; // мин атака
     static int maxFistAtack = strenght + 2; // макс атака

     static int agility = 3;

static int stamina =4; // Выносливость
static int quantityOfHels=stamina*6; //количество жизней


     }
```

Пока реализовал только возможность игры с ботом. Как сделать что бы сервер соединял 2х игроков?

Comment: а 3х 4х игроков?

Comment: Какое отношение к вопросу имеет тег [tag:java-ee]?

Comment: а как вы вообще видите коммуникацию 3х клиентов?

Comment: Три клиента отправляют заявку на бой, бой начинается у тех 2их, кто раньше отправил заявку.